# Is it possible to pass array of objects or other data type to MPI.COMM_WORLD.Scatter?

Tags: java, mpi, mpj-express

I am digging through documentation but I still can't figure out how to use other data types than array of `int`s. Is there any way to send data other than array of ints? The below code works fine if I use an array just of integers. I tried replacing `MPI.INT` with `MPI.OBJECT` but that doesn't work as well. Here's an example of sending some data to all procs except root.

```
import mpi.*;

public class MPIHello {

    static class Node {
        private static int data;
        public Node(int d) {
            this.data = d;
        }
        public static int getData() {
            return data;
        }
    };

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MPI.Init(args);

        int me = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
        int size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Size();

        Node[] Buf = new Node[1];
        if (me == 0)
        {
            for (int i=1; i<size; i++)
            {
                Buf[0] = new Node(13);
                MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(Buf, 0, Buf.length, MPI.INT, i, 0);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(Buf, 0, Buf.length, MPI.INT, 0, 0);

            System.out.println(Buf[0].getData());
        }

        MPI.Finalize();
    }

}
```

1) **Tried sending `Object[] arr = new Object[1];` that won't work as well**

Comment: Maybe show us your code that doesn't work and give more informations about what error/problem you encountered ?

Comment: @KiwiGM The above code doesn't work, I should've specified. When I use array of Objects instead of ints it doesn't work.

Comment: The error I get is ```java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at runtime.starter.MulticoreStarter$1.run(MulticoreStarter.java:281)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)```.